# About the orthogonality of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider a point (1,2,-3) in euclidian space.Now when I rotate this vector about y axis in anticlockwise direction by 90°,I will get a point(-3,2,-1).
Now when I do dot product for both vectors, the dot product should be 0,since the two vectors are perpendicular.But here I am getting the result as 4.Can some one help me out in understanding the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the point of rotation is $(0,2,0)$ not $(0,0,0)$ then the vectors 
$$\vec{A}=(1,2,-3)-(0,2,0)=(1,0,-3)$$
$$\vec B=(-3,2,-1)-(0,2,0)=(-3,0,-1)$$
Are orthogonals

The vectors are diferents 
[Graph the vectors](https://ggbm.at/mmmemced)

$\vec{A^*}=(1,2,-3)-(0,0,0)=(1,2,-3)$ and $\vec{B^*}=(-3,2,-1)-(0,0,0)=(-3,2,-1)$

How $$\cos\theta=\frac{|\vec{A^*}\cdot \vec{B^*}|}{||\vec{A^*}||\cdot||\vec{B^*}||}=\frac{4}{14}\implies \theta=\cos^{-1}(2/7)\approx73.4^\circ$$ therefore $\vec{A^*}$ and $\vec{B^*}$  are not ortoghonals

Comment: No my doubt if i rotate it with respect to origin,is it not perpendicular

Comment: This is another question, In 3D the rotation is more Complex that in 2D, is necessary has a axis of rotation. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix the section: Rotation matrix from axis and angle.

Comment: I would like to know just if it is perpendicular or not.So that the operation a.b will be clear to me.The above example i have given is perpendicular even with respect to origin,because initially lets consider the point to be in x-z plane.Now rotate the point with respect to y axis and now give the y coordinate to both the lines .They are perpendicular even now.Then why isnt dot product working here

Comment: See the new edition, are diferents vectors